# Is enum a type of array?

Tags: arrays, enums

I'm doing a project for my Java class, and it needs to involve an array. I wanted to know if enum would count as an array. My teacher will not be in class for the next week and there is no one else to ask. Any input is good.

Comment: Although you iterate over both the values of an array and a enum. Enums and arrays are both completely different data structures. Check this quora article : https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-array-and-enum-in-Java

Answer (score 0):

No, Enum and Array are distinct types.

Comment: @AlexanderDawson Do you mind accepting the answer if you don't require further assistance? Thank you.